# Pyspark: Pad Array[Int] column with zeros

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have the following column in a pyspark dataframe, of type Array[Int].

```
+--------------------+
|     feature_indices|
+--------------------+
|                 [0]|
|[0, 1, 4, 10, 11,...|
|           [0, 1, 2]|
|                 [1]|
|                 [0]|
+--------------------+
```

I am trying to pad the array with zeros, and then limit the list length, so that the length of each row's array would be the same. For example, for n = 5, I expect:

```
+--------------------+
|     feature_indices|
+--------------------+
|     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|   [0, 1, 4, 10, 11]|
|     [0, 1, 2, 0, 0]|
|     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
+--------------------+
```

Any suggestions? I looked at pyspark `rpad` function, but it only operates on string type columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a `udf` to do this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

pad_fix_length = F.udf(
    lambda arr: arr[:5] + [0] * (5 - len(arr[:5])), 
    ArrayType(IntegerType())
)

df.withColumn('feature_indices', pad_fix_length(df.feature_indices)).show()
+-----------------+
|  feature_indices|
+-----------------+
|  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|[0, 1, 4, 10, 11]|
|  [0, 1, 2, 0, 0]|
|  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
|  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I was struggling with composing the udf properly.

Comment: What if we don't give `ArrayType(IntegerType())` in udf then?

Comment: Is there a way to do without pandasUDF? Its a costly computation and with size of data what i have, its though to use pandasUDF.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used the `pad_sequences` function within Keras to do something similar. I'm not sure of your usecase so this might be an unnecessarily large dependency to add on.

Anyways, here's the link to the documentation for the function: https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#pad_sequences

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences    

input_sequence =[[1,2,3], [1,2], [1,4]]

padded_sequence = pad_sequences(input_sequence, maxlen=3, padding='post', truncating='post', value=0.0)

print padded_sequence
```

The output:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 0]
 [1 4 0]]
```